# How to make a full screen web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make a full-screen web application having the height and width set to 100% of the browser window with a flexible grid structure to shuffle div structures?

I am working on a web application and my challenge is to prepare a full-screen webpage.
I need a plugin that helps me to fit my UI structure.
I'd prefer a flexible fluid plugin.

I.e.: fill.js

Kindly provide some better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your header.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have need of :

```
 var viewport = {
        width  : $(window).width(),
        height : $(window).height()
    };
```

then use `viewport.width` and `viewport.height` in your JS code to manage your elements, page & so third.